# ( (Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)? in R

Tags: r

I am trying to execute a select query on a small data frame using "sqldf" library and getting the below error:

( (Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)? )

Tried options(expressions=500000) then it is throwing Cstack Overflow error.

In the data frame there is column with "Date" and formatted that in date format in R.

If we consider that column as "char" we are not facing any error and getting the output.

In-fact the same data frame and same R code are working in few systems and in few it not. not understanding the issue, all the systems are same configuration and same OS.

Please help me in this.... Thanks in advance.

Yugandhar

Comment: Something must be different, and if you can't see it with all the code and systems in front of you then we have no chance of seeing it with just your error messages.

Answer (score 2):

I was having exactly the same problem with a date converted from a char field.

I resolved it by casting the dates to a factor as well, like (in data.table language):

```
table[,ActualDate:=as.factor(as.date(CharacterDate))]
```

Hope that helps

Andy.